# correlated random effect model and linear mixed model

Tags: mixed-model

I would like to study the effect of financial inclusion on food security for 23 countries for the periods 2011, 2014 and 2017. I want to use a model with correlated random effects (although I couldn't find a good justification apart from  the fact that it brings together in the same regression the fixed effects model and the random effects model).

Is the model appropriate? How to justify it?
Is the correlated random effects model the same as the linear mixed model? (I'm a little confused)
thank you

Comment: Welcome to the site! "I want to use a model with correlated random effects", can you help us understand what aspect of your data/problem motivated this?

Comment: What motivates me to use the model is the ability to combine fixed effects and random effects in the same model.